# CSS Sprites are reverting to a:hover event due to PHP statementcommentary

Tags: php, css, sprite, if-statement

I'm using CSS sprites for my wordpress navigation, and in order to get them to work I needed to use a php to show tell the current page for the section.

The CSS:

```
#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.visionside a {width:204px; height:53px; background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/vision2.png)  0px 0}
#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.visionside a:hover {background-position:0px -53px}


#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.teamside a {width:204px; height:53px; background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/team2.png)  0px 0}
#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.teamside a:hover {background-position:0px -53px}


#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.mtlside a {width:204px; height:53px; background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/mtl2.png)  0px 0}
#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.mtlside a:hover {background-position:0px -53px}


#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.blogside a {width:204px; height:53px; background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/content2.png)  0px 0}
#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.blogside a:hover {background-position:0px -53px}


#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.orgside a {width:204px; height:53px; background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/org2.png)  0px 0}
#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.orgside a:hover {background-position:0px -53px}
```

The CSS in the Header to be triggered by the PHP:

```
#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.<?php echo $current1; ?> {
    background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/vision2.png)  0px -106px;
}

#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.<?php echo $current2; ?> {
    background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/team2.png)  0px -106px;
}

#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.<?php echo $current3; ?> {
    background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/content2.png)  0px -106px;
}

#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.<?php echo $current4; ?> {
    background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/org2.png)  0px -106px;
}
```

The PHP:

```
 <?php
  if ( is_page('vision') ) { $current1 = 'visionside a'; }
  elseif  ( is_page('team') ) { $current2 = 'teamside a'; }
  elseif  ( is_page('commentary') ) { $current3 = 'blogside a'; }
  elseif  ( is_page('organizations') ) { $current4 = 'orgside a'; }
 ?>
```

But when the user hovers over the navigation the item shows the hover state, NOT the active state as it should.

The URL:  http://jumpthru.net/newsite/vision/

Comment: Pekka, I'm sorry, I posted some of the incorrect CSS that targeted a different set of sprites.  I meant no disrespect, and am greatful to the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Pekka, if you could repost the changes I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a spectacularly poor way to be doing it. Ignoring common sense:

You could just add `!important` to each of your `background` properties, for example:

```
background:url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/vision2.png)  0px -106px !important;
```

---

You're doing it subtlety different from the way WordPress suggests:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Dynamic_Menu_Highlighting

I think you should read that tutorial more carefully, and redo this.

Comment: Can you point out what my spectacularly poor way of doing it is?  I'm here trying to learn, not just to be criticized.  I used the wordpress link you showed above as a reference, so if you could let me know what I'm doing so poorly I can try to fix it.

Comment: I didn't just criticise, I gave you a fix to what you had ;) Alright, being more specific. You have four things that look like `#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.<?php echo $current1; ?>`. For the pages that aren't "current", the selector will look like `#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.`, which is not valid CSS. You should move the dot to inside the PHP variable. But, that's not really it either. You should add a class "current" to the HTML of the current page's `<li>`, and then have something like `#sidebarnav ul#sidenav li.visionside.current { CSS for active visionside here }`. That would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I agree mostly with what @thirtydot says as there's probably an easier WP way to add a class to an active link.. but to follow your logic you can make the whole thing much simpler.

First the CSS. though I did copy a bit more from your page file, you can remove a whole lot of those repeated declarations, so that the only thing each specific link needs  is the background-image.. the original size, background-position etc does not change so something like this makes it easier to read:

```
#sidenav {
    width:204px; 
    list-style:none; 
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    float:left;
}

#sidenav li {
    float:left;
    width: 100%; 
}

#sidenav li a {
    display: block;
    height:53px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

#sidenav li a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -53px;
}

#sidenav li.visionside a {background-image : url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/vision2.png);}
#sidenav li.teamside a {background-image : url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/team2.png);}
#sidenav li.mtlside a {background-image : url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/mtl2.png);}
#sidenav li.blogside a {background-image: url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/content2.png);}
#sidenav li.orgside a {background-image: url(http://jumpthru.net/newsite/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/side/org2.png);}
```

now your "active" state only needs the one relevant link to have it's `background-position` changed to `0 -106px` - no need to re-declare the image again

so your PHP logic could be this (possibly even simpler) but I'm trying to use what you have:

```
 <?php
  if ( is_page('vision') ) { $current = 'visionside'; }
  elseif  ( is_page('team') ) { $current = 'teamside'; }
  elseif  ( is_page('???') ) { $current = 'mtlside'; }
  elseif  ( is_page('commentary') ) { $current = 'blogside'; }
  elseif  ( is_page('organizations') ) { $current = 'orgside'; }
 ?>
```

Note: the same variable is used (and question marks would need replacing for your mtlside link).. and then the line in the `<head>` styles only then need read:

```
#sidenav li.<?php echo $current ?> a {
    background-position: 0px -106px;
}
```

That way it will only be the one link which is getting more specific showing the "active page" background-position.

I'm not sure what you actually want your hover to do, but the `a:hover` rule will not override the new "active" selector because the rule in the `<head>` styles above is more specific, if you actually want the the active link to show the same `:hover` state as normal you need to make the `a:hover` rule in the stylesheet more specific which you can do like this:

```
#sidebarnav #sidenav li a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -53px;
}
```

note I removed the double `ID` 's from the stylesheet selectors as there is no need for them, one ID is unique enough.. but then you can use the second ID (#sidebarnav) if required to make that last rule "weigh" more if specificity is then required.

Comment: For what it's worth, the OP asked another question about this, and has seemingly decided to implement the accepted answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318699/css-sprites-and-php-using-dynamic-menu-highlighting-not-working-with-loop-funtion

Comment: @thirtydot, Thanks never saw it :)